# Touch ID to wake up macbook pro 2018, only works sometimes

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

Sometimes I am able to wake up my Macbook from a completely black screen with just the touch ID. But sometimes I have to press a keyboard key or move the mouse before using the touch ID in order to wake up the Macbook. I don't seem to know the reason, does anyone know?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.